# Enable TImage to open JPEGs, GIFs and PNGs in Delphi XE3?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, timage

I'm looking to reuse some code that draws a images on a device context in a dll. It uses TImage which works fine in the Original program. But in the dll BMPs and TIFFs load fine but it throws an error loading JPGs PNGs and GIFs which the original loaded fine. I'm having troble finding anything in the original code to enable them. I see in Vcl.Graphics that it looks to see if CLR is defined which I tried adding to the Conditional defines of the project but that didn't work. I can't seem to find any other option in the project settings that I'm missing to enable the CLR.

Comment: Sertac has the answer. The CLR conditionals pertain to the now moribund .net compiler. Ignore those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Include `jpeg`, `pngimage` and `gifimg` to your `uses` clause. These units enable the usage of the corresponding image types and register their file extensions.